# Font not changing in output

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to program my Portfolio website as a beginner and trying to put in some font I found from the internet. I preloaded the font, tried different fonts, changed the code from ttf to both woff and woff2, font works in the demo HTML file that comes with formating it. Both Chrome and Mozzila says that the font-family is Neutral Face. It just won't change. Honestly, I feel like I have tried everything but ask here. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: added the part where I test the font the most. At first I tried to use the body font family but upon seeing the font not changing I tried to directly add it to the nav h1.

```
CSS
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Neutral Face';
  src: url("/assets/css/fonts/NeutralFaceRegular.woff2") format('woff2'),
      url("/assets/css/fonts/NeutralFaceRegular.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Neutral Face';
  src: url("/assets/css/fonts/NeutralFaceBold.woff2") format('woff2'),
      url("/assets/css/fonts/NeutralFaceBold.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}



/* Variables */
:root {
  --font-family: 'Neutral Face', sans-serf;
  --normal-font: 400;
  --bold-font: 700;
  --bolder-font: 900;
  --bg-color: #fcfcfc;
  --primary-color: #99ff00;
  --secondary-color: #CD3290;
  --primary-shadow: #8b8eaf;
  --secondary-shadow: #7c7c7c;
  --bottom-margin: 0.5rem;
  --bottom-margin-2: 1rem;
  --line-height: 1.7rem;
  --transition: 0.3s;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav h1 {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-family: 'Neutral Face', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  letter-spacing: .05em
}
HTML
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav>
        <h1>Martin Ploig</h1>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: We need to see more of the context. Where are you asking an element to use that font? (And why is the font-face being set twice?). Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth From what I have read I thought setting it once for normal font and once for bold fond. (that's how the files downloaded after converting.) Also honestly there isn't much more to say. It doesn't show even on basic h1 text anywhere on the website. All the browsers say that the text is using "Neutral Face" font family and that it isn't being overshadowed/ overruled by anything so I am not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Could you just put up a little snippet that shows the problem. Just a div where you have set the font would probably do. The code you have given does not show how you are giving a particular element a particular font so it’s not possible to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @AHaworth For sure!